# Looking for a way to do less locking while caching

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am using the code below to cache items.  It's pretty basic.

The issue I have is that every time it caches an item, section of the code locks.  So with roughly a million items arriving every hour or so, this is a problem.

I've tried creating a dictionary of static lock objects per cacheKey, so that locking is granular, but that in itself becomes an issue with managing expiration of them, etc...

Is there a better way to implement minimal locking?

```
private static readonly object cacheLock = new object();
public static T GetFromCache<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> GetData) where T : class {

    // Returns null if the string does not exist, prevents a race condition
    // where the cache invalidates between the contains check and the retrieval.
    T cachedData = MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as T;

    if (cachedData != null) {
        return cachedData;
    }

    lock (cacheLock) {
        // Check to see if anyone wrote to the cache while we where
        // waiting our turn to write the new value.
        cachedData = MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as T;

        if (cachedData != null) {
            return cachedData;
        }

        // The value still did not exist so we now write it in to the cache.
        cachedData = GetData();

        MemoryCache.Default.Set(cacheKey, cachedData, new CacheItemPolicy(...));
        return cachedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you have a million cache requests per hour, but how often are you creating new caches?  If you only have 5 caches and they're cleared every 30 minutes on average,  your locking accounts for basically none of your overhead.  If you're populating 10 caches every 30 seconds on the other hand, your locking strategy is going to add a lot of overhead.  it also matters how often you're requesting items from different caches that aren't populated.  If it's a lot, you shouldn't do this, if it's not, this is unlikely the bottleneck.

Comment: @Servy Million `new` items arriving during the course of an hour.  So a lock will be established, item fetched, and added to cache.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to consider using [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netcore-2.2), which you can obtain write lock only when needed.

Using `cacheLock.EnterReadLock();` and `cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();` should greatly improve the performance.

That link I gave even have an example of a cache, exactly what you need, I copy here:

```
public class SynchronizedCache 
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private Dictionary<int, string> innerCache = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public int Count
    { get { return innerCache.Count; } }

    public string Read(int key)
    {
        cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return innerCache[key];
        }
        finally
        {
            cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void Add(int key, string value)
    {
        cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            innerCache.Add(key, value);
        }
        finally
        {
            cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public bool AddWithTimeout(int key, string value, int timeout)
    {
        if (cacheLock.TryEnterWriteLock(timeout))
        {
            try
            {
                innerCache.Add(key, value);
            }
            finally
            {
                cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public AddOrUpdateStatus AddOrUpdate(int key, string value)
    {
        cacheLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        try
        {
            string result = null;
            if (innerCache.TryGetValue(key, out result))
            {
                if (result == value)
                {
                    return AddOrUpdateStatus.Unchanged;
                }
                else
                {
                    cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
                    try
                    {
                        innerCache[key] = value;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
                    }
                    return AddOrUpdateStatus.Updated;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
                try
                {
                    innerCache.Add(key, value);
                }
                finally
                {
                    cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
                }
                return AddOrUpdateStatus.Added;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            cacheLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int key)
    {
        cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            innerCache.Remove(key);
        }
        finally
        {
            cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public enum AddOrUpdateStatus
    {
        Added,
        Updated,
        Unchanged
    };

    ~SynchronizedCache()
    {
       if (cacheLock != null) cacheLock.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how `MemoryCache.Default` is implemented, or whether or not you have control over it.
But in general, prefer using `ConcurrentDictionary` over `Dictionary` with lock in a multi threaded environment.

`GetFromCache` would just become

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, T> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>();
...
cache.GetOrAdd("someKey", (key) =>
{
  var data = PullDataFromDatabase(key);
  return data;
});
```

There are two more things to take care about.

#### Expiry

Instead of saving `T` as the value of the dictionary, you can define a type

```
struct CacheItem<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }
}
```

And store the cache as a `CacheItem` with a defined expiry.

```
cache.GetOrAdd("someKey", (key) =>
{
    var data = PullDataFromDatabase(key);
    return new CacheItem<T>() { Item = data, Expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)) };
});
```

Now you can implement expiration in an asynchronous thread.

```
Timer expirationTimer = new Timer(ExpireCache, null, 60000, 60000);
...
void ExpireCache(object state)
{
    var needToExpire = cache.Where(c => DateTime.UtcNow >= c.Value.Expiry).Select(c => c.Key);
    foreach (var key in needToExpire)
    {
        cache.TryRemove(key, out CacheItem<T> _);
    }
}
```

Once a minute, you search for all cache entries that need to be expired, and remove them.

#### "Locking"

Using `ConcurrentDictionary` guarantees that simultaneous read/writes won't corrupt the dictionary or throw an exception.
But, you can still end up with a situation where two simultaneous reads cause you to fetch the data from the database twice.

One neat trick to solve this is to wrap the value of the dictionary with `Lazy`

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<CacheItem<T>>> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<CacheItem<T>>>();
...
var data = cache.GetOrData("someKey", key => new Lazy<CacheItem<T>>(() => 
{
    var data = PullDataFromDatabase(key);
    return new CacheItem<T>() { Item = data, Expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)) };
})).Value;
```

**Explanation**

with `GetOrAdd` you might end up invoking the "get from database if not in cache" delegate multiple times in the case of simultaneous requests.
However, `GetOrAdd` will end up using only one of the values that the delegate returned, and by returning a `Lazy`, you guaranty that only one `Lazy` will get invoked.

Comment: You're now never expiring anything, and potentially doing the work to load caches multiple times.  The OP's code has neither problem.

Comment: The trick with Lazy<T> is problematic (or has been in other implementations) because if the `PullFromDatabase` returns an exception, it will save the exception in cache.  Isn't that right?

Comment: @AngryHacker You are right, I haven't though about it. I guess a way around it would be to catch the exception inside the lazy delegate and set the cache to null in the `catch` block. Then, check the check to see if it's null. if so, remove the item from cache (and throw an exception if needed).